# subscriber and if-else/switch-case statement

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, I am new to ROS and having a bit of problems when using subscriber. I am writing a leader following function and trying to subscribe to a rostopic under a conditional statement, switch statement in this case, but it doesn't work. Key lines of the problem are shown below:

```
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "mycontrol_1");

  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::Subscriber h_sub = n.subscribe("/uav1/sonar_height",1000,hcontrol);

  switch (squad_leader_no){

    case 1:

      {ros::Subscriber splitcmd_sub = n.subscribe("/uav1/split_cmd", 1000, getsplitcmd);

      break;}

    case 2:

      {ros::Subscriber splitcmd_sub = n.subscribe("/uav2/split_cmd", 1000, getsplitcmd);

      break;}

    case 3:

      {ros::Subscriber splitcmd_sub = n.subscribe("/uav3/split_cmd", 1000, getsplitcmd);

      break;}

    case 4:

      {ros::Subscriber splitcmd_sub = n.subscribe("/uav4/split_cmd", 1000, getsplitcmd);

      break;}

  }

...

  // loop rate of 35Hz

  ros::Rate cycle(35);

...
```

In above case, subscription fails. But when I pull the subscriber out of the conditional statement, it subscribe successfully. Could anybody be helpful on this problem if know why, please? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189706/subscriber-and-if-else/switch-case-statement/) by [PJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/19993/pj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-08-11**:
what do you mean by "subscription fails" , you are using same callback function for all subcriptions, so for all message it will get called. I mean once you get case 1 ,  for next your callback will be called for all messages from uav1. I missed the scope part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Read the Publisher Subsriber Tutorial carefully:

> When all copies of the Subscriber object go out of scope, this callback will automatically be unsubscribed from this topic.

And this is exactly what happens to you. The subscriber goes out of scope and unsubscribes.

Oh I just have seen even your variable `splitcmd_sub` goes out of scope after each case.

Have a look at C++ scoping.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/19993/pj/) on 2014-08-11**:
I have seen what happens and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Create the variable outside of the switch statement and initialize it within the switch statements. Use one subscriber variable for you cmd_vel, and now this way you wont go out of scope.

```
main(int argc, char **argv) {  
ros::init(argc, argv, "mycontrol_1");

 ros::NodeHandle n;

 ros::Subscriber h_sub = n.subscribe("/uav1/sonar_height",1000,hcontrol);
 ros::Subscriber splitcmd_sub;

switch (squad_leader_no)
{

case 1:
       splitcmd_sub = n.subscribe("/uav1/split_cmd", 1000, getsplitcmd);
       break;

case 2:
       splitcmd_sub = n.subscribe("/uav2/split_cmd", 1000, getsplitcmd);
       break;

case 3:
       splitcmd_sub = n.subscribe("/uav3/split_cmd", 1000, getsplitcmd);
       break;

.....
}
```

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2014-08-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/19993/pj/) on 2014-08-11**:
I have seen what the problem is and thanks for your comment!